# How do we enforce writing java comments for team projects on jenkins?

Tags: java, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, javadoc, checkstyle

We need to enforce the usage of comments in our team project java code. Since we are already using Jenkins, it is preferable that we use a plugin that can cause the build to succeed/fail based on whether comments are written. Options include using Checkstyle, git hooks or SONAR plugins to enforce the same. Appreciate any pointers or tips to set this up.

Note that we intend to use Javadocs for commenting purpose.

Comment: fire them if they don't.

Comment: hahah!  @Stultuske

Comment: Really, that is the only way that works. Anyone can write comment that passes a validation but is still completely useless, and unless the devs understand the need of *useful* comments, that's what you'll end up with.

Comment: What should the metric be for your plugin? Lines of comments, all parameters commented, ...?
Forcing comments by an automated tool will be completely useless and demotivating in most cases (useless commenting of setters/getters; good code style > lots of comments; lots of comment text does not consolidate quality).
The only sane way to introduce meaningful comments in your code is peer code review and getting your developers on board on why comments are useful.

Comment: I also think this is not the question of metrics and build environments. This is a "Do your freakin' job" kinda thing. I've never heard of any successful try for enforcing useful comments by metrics and build tools. I've heard many failed ones.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Checkstyle plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin) is a viable option.

It could even meet your requirement to "*cause the build to succeed/fail based on whether comments are written*" if Checkstyle was configured to only to check for issues relating to comments, but you probably wouldn't want to do that, since Checkstyle can also help to improve code quality and consistency in so many other ways.

Build options include:

- Configure a Jenkins project build to fail if the number of Checkstyle errors exceeds some absolute limit. (e.g. Fail this build if the number of Checkstyle errors is > 300.)
- Configure a Jenkins project build to fail if the number of Checkstyle errors exceeds the number of errors of the previous build by some defined threshold. (e.g. Fail this build if the number of Checkstyle errors is more than 50 greater than the previous build.)

However, I believe both of these approaches would be system wide, applying to all builds. I don't think that you can set those thresholds on a per-project basis.

Other points worth noting about using [Checkstyle for policing Javadoc comments](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html):

- Any Checkstyle error message can be customized to meet your needs.
- You can allow missing comments on getters/setters using **allowMissingPropertyJavadoc**.
- You can specify that method names conforming to some regular expression will be ignored using **ignoreMethodNamesRegex**.
- You can specify that methods below a certain threshold of line count can be allowed to omit a Javadoc comment using **minLineCount**.
- You can configure Checkstyle to accept a Javadoc comment that does not exactly match the method's signature, return type and thrown exceptions using **allowMissingThrowsTags**, **allowMissingReturnTag** and **allowMissingParamTags** (though I'm not clear on why anyone would want to do that).

It's easy to identify specific areas where Checkstyle is less than perfect, and of course it won't (can't) review the quality of your comments, but those are not arguments for not using it. Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good; Checkstyle will verify that minimal requirements for Javadoc comments are being met.